# List items according to the first letter of Items

Tags: php, html, mysql

In my site i need to display all the products in a single page.
let me explain it further.
Details of items will be saved in mysql table.I need to create a Brand Directory Page using that items.
If there are Items Starting from Letter A,

**A**

- Armani
- Anan
- Aungudo

And items starting from B,

**B**

- Bacardi
- Barloni

Like that A-Z i need to display.But i am new to PHP and Tried to create a logic but didnt come with anything.
so please can anyone help me on that??>

Thanks in Advance.

A quick reply will be so nice.

THANKS

Comment: Can you show your mysql query ? Are you using Order By ?

Comment: yes i am using ORDERBY CLAUSE IN MY SQL QUERY...this is my query  SELECT  DISTINCT name, id FROM other   ORDER BY name

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
$sql       = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ......");

$res       = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
   $title  = $row['title'];
   $letter = substr($title, 0, 1);
   $res[$letter][] = $title;
}

ksort($res);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

Comment: Nice approach, the other answers are just showing the sql request and I think this is not the most complicated part!

Answer (score 1):

You say you're using MySQL, but for some reason want to do the sorting in PHP. Are you aware of the [ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) construct in (My)SQL?

This makes it very easy to sort your records alphabetically even before they enter PHP. Imagine a query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT name 
FROM table
```

Then you could imagine getting a result like:

```
John
Abe
Pete
Frank
```

But when you use the ORDER BY construct and turn your query into:

```
SELECT name 
FROM table
ORDER BY name
```

You get the result in alphabetical order (default for textual data types)

```
Abe
Frank
John
Pete
```

If you decide you would rather sort descending, simply use `ORDER BY name DESC` (or `ASC` to explicitly order ascendingly)

Comment: Oops, I think I miss-interpreted your question to be 'How do I sort alphabetically' rather than 'How do I print grouped records in PHP'.

Comment: yes Joost,this is how to group records.this not exactly what i want.but really appreciate your support

Answer (score 0):

Try order by in mysql query

```
SELECT id,name from TABLE order by name asc;
```

Now search for char 'A' at starting from what you received from your query and create the block accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest this way of approach:

1. Sort your list of results first in mysql as @SudipPal suggested.
2. Iterate through the sorted items using a `for` loop
3. Gather all the 'A's and push them into a new associative array with the `key` as 'A'
4. Repeat for the rest of the letters

You should end up with an associative array like this structure:

```
array(
    "A" => array("Armani", "Anan", "Aungundo"),
    "B" => array("Bacardi", "Barloni"),
    "C" => ... ,
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using Mysql query like this :

```
$letter = 'a'; // or 'b' ... 'z'
$q = mysql_query(" select * from `my_table` where `my_coloumn` like '".$letter."%'  ");
while($r = mysql_fetch_object($q))
{
    echo $r->my_cloumn.'<br />';
}
```